# Flutter: knowing if the front camera is mirroring the image

Tags: flutter, camera, face-detection

I'm implementing live face detection feature in a Flutter app, the problem is that the front camera is mirroring the image in some phone types while the others not

it's easy to mirror the marking rectangle too, but I can't determine if mirroring takes place or not

Isn't there a programmatic way to detect mirroring, or to prevent it?

Comment: I'm just starting on an app component that will use the camera, and researching this now, as it was a problem in the previous (Swift) version.  It might help if you listed the "some phone types" where it is and is not happening.  Also, there are existing workarounds here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27650

Answer (score 1):

For existing workarounds mentioned: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27650

Don't forget import these modules:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap; 
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory; 
import android.graphics.Matrix;  
import android.util.DisplayMetrics; 
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
```